# joining points with tradingview's charting library

Tags: tradingview-api

Using the charting-library, I have a chart with hourly candles, but my custom study has data points daily.

This shows like that:

[image]

Where you can see the stacks of little lines at the beginning of each day.

How can I join these points into lines?

This is the code that sets the plots:

```
plots: [
    {id: 'channel1', type: 'line'},
    {id: 'channel2', type: 'line'},
    {id: 'channel3', type: 'line'},
    {id: 'channel4', type: 'line'},
    {id: 'channel5', type: 'line'}
],

defaults: {
    styles: {
        channel1: { linestyle: 0, visible: true, linewidth: 2, plottype: 2, trackPrice: false, transparency: 40, color: '#FF00FF' },
        channel2: { linestyle: 0, visible: true, linewidth: 2, plottype: 2, trackPrice: false, transparency: 40, color: '#0f37ff' },
        channel3: { linestyle: 0, visible: true, linewidth: 2, plottype: 2, trackPrice: false, transparency: 40, color: '#ff0000' },
        channel4: { linestyle: 0, visible: true, linewidth: 2, plottype: 2, trackPrice: false, transparency: 40, color: '#2aab4e' },
        channel5: { linestyle: 0, visible: true, linewidth: 2, plottype: 2, trackPrice: false, transparency: 40, color: '#2880c2' },
    }
```